# How to wait until the dialog is really closed

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, showdialog

The software starts thread with some calculations and then shows another `Form` as a waiting dialog with `ShowDialog`. When the `BackgroundWorker` thread finishes its work, the `Form` is closed in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and another calculation is start with another `Form` as a waiting dialog (with `ShowDialog` again).

The problem is that the first waiting dialog is still visible until the second waiting dialog is closed. How to wait with showing the second dialog after the first dialog is really closed?

Simple code to reproduce:

```
private BackgroundWorker _bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
private Form2 _msg = new Form2();
private Form3 _msg2 = new Form3();

public Form1()
{
    _bgw.DoWork += BgwDoWork;
    _bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += BgwRunWorkerCompleted;
    _bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    _msg.ShowDialog();
}

private void BgwDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

private void BgwRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _msg.Close();
    _msg2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps im not understanding you correctly, but in your code _msg.Close() is before _msg2.ShowDialog(), your problem is that while your code is well written it doesnt work as intended? if this is your problem just add in between those 2 things the following line Application.DoEvents(); and this show do the trick

Comment: That is not true. `Application.DoEvents()` doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that ShowDialog() is a blocking call. You still have not returned from the constructor when you show _msg2.

This is a quick fix:

```
public Form1()
{
    _bgw.DoWork += BgwDoWork;
    _bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += BgwRunWorkerCompleted;
    _bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    _msg.ShowDialog();
    _msg2.ShowDialog();   // here
}

private void BgwRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _msg.Close();
    //_msg2.ShowDialog();  // not here
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but how to do this behaviour if I know only after the calculation if I need the second dialog? Is there a way or do I have to save the results to some private property and then evaluate it *in the method* from which I call the `ShowDialog`?

Comment: Sure, you can use DialogRsult ( instead of _msg.Close() ) or add a property to Form2 or ...

Comment: But you can get a better, more natural flow by replacing the Bgw with a Task and then use async & await.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to make some *minor* changes to the old project written with `.NET framework 4` so `async` and `await` is something I *have to forget* for a while :-)